# SeekBarPreference doesn't seem to persist its value

Tags: android, slider, seekbar, persist

I have a `SeekBarPreference` in an XML file which displays (and the slider works), but after I click the `OK` button, the value just seems to disappear.

This is my XML file...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <SeekBarPreference android:key="NOTE_MINIMUM"
        android:summary="Set the lowest note in the playback sound"
        android:max="125" 
        android:title="Lowest note" 
        android:persistent="true"
        android:defaultValue="25" />

    <CheckBoxPreference android:key="COLOR_CODING"
        android:title="Show playback progress bar" 
        android:summary="string/color_coding_summary"
        android:defaultValue="true" />
</PreferenceScreen>
```

I can get the value of the `COLOR_CODING` field in my code, but not the `NOTE_MINIMUM` field, which comes back as an unknown field using `prefs.getInt("NOTE_MINIMUM", -11);`

But I think the problem is in the preferences dialog. When I check the `COLOR_CODING` box and close then open the `PreferencesScreen`, it's state persists. When I move the slider on the `NOTE_MINIMUM` dialog (and click `OK`), doing a close-reopen of the app shows the slider as it was when the app initialised, with the slider at beginning of its track.

Could anyone please help me with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Answered.

In the end I created (cut and pasted someone's) `SeekBarPreference` code and made it into a class in my app amd called that rather than the api class.

However, this is not so much an answer as a workaround.

I still don't understand why the android `SeekBarPreference` but it doesn't store its result in the same way that the android `CheckBoxPreference` does (with no additional app code listener needed to capture it's state).

I'd still be interested to see another answer as this roll your own code seems to be the method everyone else uses.